# How do I get results from my http response?

Tags: http, response

I'm trying to figure out how this HttpClient works. In particular, I'm trying to figure out how to get the results from the response.

I've got a controller that sends a request to a web API.

Here's the API function that handles the request:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetProjects()
    {
    // Get a list of projects.
    // Convert projects from Entity Framework entities to ViewModels.
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, projectModelList);
    }
```

Here's how I'm sending the request:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIBaseAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

...

var requestJSONString = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
result = client.SendAsync(requestJSONString).Result;
```

The result I get doesn't have the list of projects. I looks like this instead:

How do I get the list of project from the response?

I've been doing this so far:

```
var jsonStringTask = 
client.SendAsync(requestJSONString).ContinueWith(jsonStringResponse =>
{
var jsonStringTask2 = jsonStringResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(jsonStringResponse2 =>
{
    jsonString = jsonStringResponse2.Result;
});

jsonStringTask2.Wait();
});
```

^ But this seems like major overkill. Why should I have to run ContiueWith on the response, and then ContinueWith AGAIN on the results of the first ContinueWith, and then get the results from the response. I also don't like json. I'd like to get the list of projects directly from the response right after I call SendAsync(...) as a list of projects.

Is there not a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think your code should look like something like:

```
var result = await client.SendAsync(requestJSONString)
```

after adding the `await` you should have your data in `result`.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to work for me.

I put two lines of code like this:

```
        result = await client.SendAsync(securityTokenRequest);
        var result2 = ((Task<HttpResponseMessage>)result).Result;
```

I put breakpoints on each. I don't get to the second breakpoint. The call to SendAsync just hangs, like the request got lost on its way to the API.